# Applying cumulative usage to road sections

Tags: sdna

I would like to calculate the total 'weight' of goods which will travel
across *each* road section of a roading network.

Goods (from a nearby polygon) will arrive at the closest road section, and then travel along subsequent road sections to the destination. So, road sections nearest the destination will have multiple loads travelling over it which need to be added together. Example image is here.[image]

Someone suggested sDNA may be able to do this. Any advice that this is the case? Or any alternative solutions? Have got Mapinfo 12 & QGIS 2.14 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking to calculate is called *weighted betweenness*. [sDNA+](http://www.cardiff.ac.uk/sdna/sdna-plus/) running in QGIS will do it so long as the weights appear in a data field on the network (more on this below).

Are you calculating transport to a single destination to which all goods travel? In sDNA+ set origin weight set to the weight of each nearby polygon and destination weight set to 1 for the destination, 0 elsewhere. (Actually for a large data set the calculation will be quicker if you reverse origin and destination weight and put `skipzeroweightorigins` in [sDNA advanced config](http://www.cardiff.ac.uk/sdna/wp-content/downloads/documentation/manual/sDNA_manual_v3_4_5/guide_to_individual_tools.html#advanced-config-options-for-sdna-integral-and-geometry-tools). For small data set it won't matter).

Alternatively if different goods have different destinations sDNA+ will allow input of an O-D matrix to specify this.

Standard sDNA calculates weighted betweenness with the restriction that origin and destination weights must be the same (so goods would be routed between all polygons subject to a maximum trip distance).

Finally, how to get the polygon weights onto the network? This is a fairly standard spatial join task in GIS; I'm more familiar with Arc myself and not well versed in the options available for this in QGIS and Mapinfo but they will be there:

1. join each polygon to the nearest network link thus putting a unique link identifier on the polygon
2. join each link to the polygon by identifier thus putting polygon weight data on *some* links. Copy the data if this is a dynamic join.
3. On the copied data, run a query to find all links with `null` polygon weight and set these nulls to 0

If you have any particularly long links, and the loss of accuracy is important to you, you may wish to automatically split long links into several shorter ones (I think tools exist to do this - simple option) or alternatively write a script to add links from each polygon to the existing network to get the join on the link in exactly the right place.